# iOS Run particular installed game from my app running in Guided Access

Tags: ios

I am developing an app for Ipad which will run in Guided Access. in this app I have a Entertainment tab which will open particular game installed on device and user should also get back to app again when exits. this all should run in Guided Access only.
is it possible to use custom URL scheme in Guided Access? and what if I don't know the URL of that particular game?

please help.

Comment: "Kiosk" mode? Are you talking about Guided Access?

Comment: @Marcus Adams : yes Guided Access

Answer (score 3):

URLs do not open up in Guided Access mode. You can't even open one up in Safari. There is currently no way to switch between apps in Guided Access mode.

Perhaps you don't want guided access mode. You can lock the iPad down so that no apps can be installed or deleted (without PIN), and lock down the web browser, etc., through settings Restrictions.

Comment: thanx Marcus Adams, do you know any alternative to do this?

Comment: how about having code of the game and integrating it in my app

Comment: you cannot exit Guided Access mode by holding the home button and power button on the device. i cross checked it

Comment: @Paul, you're right about exiting with power button. If your "apps" were JavaScript and you used a WebView, you could integrate them in your app, otherwise you can't.

Comment: yes you are right.. can you please explain how can this be done. when i use uiwebview to open a game say "templerun" it open up but how would i get back to my app from "templerun"?